# How to compare element position in xpath

Tags: xpath

I am trying to compare customer account values to display only different values and ignore duplicate in XPath:

XML code:

```
<info> 
  <Customer CustAccount="1"/>
  <Customer CustAccount="2"/>
  <Customer CustAccount="2"/>
  <Customer CustAccount="3"/> 
</info>
```

The result should compare customer 1/2/3 and display:

```
customer 1
customer 2
customer 3
```

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed.  Please fix, and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the XPath-2.0 expression

```
for $c in distinct-values(/info/Customer/@CustAccount) return concat('customer ',$c,'&#xa;')
```

**Output is:**

```
customer 1
customer 2
customer 3
```

If you do not like the newlines, remove the `&#xa;` from the expression.
There is no pure XPath-1.0 expression achieving this; you could only do this with XSLT-1.0 if XPath-2.0 is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pure xpath 1.0 solution.

Sample xml:

```
<root >
    <info> 
      <Customer CustAccount="1"/>
      <Customer CustAccount="2"/>
      <Customer CustAccount="2"/>
      <Customer CustAccount="3"/> 
    </info>
</root>
```

**xpath 1.0:**

```
/root/info/Customer[not(./@CustAccount=preceding::Customer/@CustAccount)]
```

Evidence:
[image]

Comment: Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: This will work similar to distinct in xpath 2.0, so you don't have to worry if there is a customer with matching custAccount down the line somewhere else.